# How does Google Analytics tag users in Custom Variables?

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

We have an page that is shown inside a software tool we have. It's a sort of "starterpage" that shows up when you start it. Our software is available as Free, Pro, and Trial.

I have set up my tracking so that people who visit this page are tagged as a "Free user" or a "Pro user" using custom variables.

I then segment my visitors in GA to show only, for example, "Free users" to see how many of these later go on and purchase the Pro-version (using a regular Goal).

The software leverages a specific browser, called the JXBrowser, and the purchase is done through the regular webpage visited through another browser (like Firefox or Chrome). I want to know how Analytics saves the tag of the user. Does it tag the IP address visiting the software starterpage or does it save it in some sort of cookie.

I'm asking because I want to know how accurate the data I'm seeing is. I am seeing that the tagging is working and that the goal completion for that usergroup is working as well. The goal completions is somewhat low though, which is why I want to make sure that isn't becuase of some technical difficulty.

**TL;DR;** Is Custom Variables tagging users IP as certain visitor-groups or are they saving the data in a cookie? How does Custom Variables work in cross-browser situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom variables available in Google Analytics [ga.js library](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables#setup) have a scope that defines whether they are attached to a pageview, visit or visitor. From your question, I would assume that you are using a visitor-level scope.

```
 _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',
      1,                   // This custom var is set to slot #1.  Required parameter.
      'Software Version',     // The name acts as a kind of category for the user activity.  Required parameter.
      'Free',               // This value of the custom variable.  Required parameter.
      3                    // Sets the scope to visitor-level.  Optional parameter.
   ]);
```

Visitor-level custom variables do indeed use a cookie to persist the value (the cookie name is __utmv).

On a side-note, GA also uses cookies for measuring unique visitors and many other things like session start / end, number of visits. This means that a user using multiple browsers will not be seen as one users, but as many users as there are different browsers (based on cookie sets).

It's worth pointing out that Google Analytics offers another collection libary designed to make tracking across browsers and devices easier, the [analytics.js library](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/). In your case, if all users are registered or have a unique 'install id' you might be better off disabling cookies storage and using your own id for the cookie - a feature available in the  [analytics.js library](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/domains#disableCookies).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can analytics.js be unsed in conjunction with ga.js? Seeing how the rest of my tracking uses ga_, can I simply switch to using analytics_ in this specific scenario? Also, they are not logged in, or have an install-id, in the free version. The trial and pro version has a license-nr, which we can probably use. But I don't really understand how that works as a substitute for saving the info in the cookie? The install-id would not be with the visitor when they visit the regular website through a regular broweser?

Comment: Also, another question: If this is saved in the cookie, how come I can see stats in Analytics. I can see people being tagged as specific usergroups, and I can also see conversions for that specific usergroup?

Comment: Read through https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ - you'll see that you can use both analytics.js and ga.js on the same page, but they need to report to separate profiles. You need to decide when you create the profile whether you will be using analytics.js or ga.js for collection, as processing is handled differently.

Comment: The way GA uses cookie data is by passing the visitor cookie ID into the utmcc parameter of the request. This is then used during processing. When you disable cookie storage on analytics.js, you are expected to provide your own client ID in replacement which is also included in the request. Make sure you read https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/cookie-usage too !

Comment: Got it. But do you have any idea as of why we I am seeing stats in Analytics, even though I'm using the regular ga_ methods. I am both seeing that people are being classified as certain usertypes. And with advanced segments I can see that those segments are converting. The classification (custom variables) is done on a browser seperate from that which they convert with.